# NuGet dependency of the same version

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget, build-server

I want to generate nuget packages automatically on our TeamCity build server. We use TeamCity AssemblyInfo Patcher to make all dlls of a specific build have the same version numbers.

We generate multiple NuGet packages from our project. How can I specify the version number in the dependency field so that it uses the same number than for the package that is being built **without hardcoding the number in the NuGet .spec file**?

As an example, `MyProject.Plugins` requires `MyProject.Math`. So for `MyProject.Plugins 1.2.3.45`, the dependency should look like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency id="MyProject.Math" version="1.2.3.45" />
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I am thinking about replacing the version as in a powershell build step so the current version being build is always enforced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeamCity's NuGet pack includes a version number field.

If you use AssemblyInfoPatcher, we can just use the number we specify there.

For more complex approaches using File Content Replacer, a small PowerShell script that reads the version number out of the compiled dll can help and stores it in the teamcity configuration parameter %ActualVersion%

```
$DllFileName = "MyDll.dll"
$PathPrefix = "bin/Release/"
$Version = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($PathPrefix + $DllFileName).FileVersion
Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='ActualVersion' value='$Version']"
```